# Oracle too much processes

Tags: oracle, process

My oracle server has a huge queue and slowly executes user requests. I have increased ram and cpu but still same problem.
I dont know anything to oracle, can you please give me commands to check if my server is configured properly to accept multithreads? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Database* don't run slowly.
The *Queries* inside them do.

Given that you have the same symptoms even after increasing RAM and CPU, that makes me think that you have poorly performing queries in need of tuning.  *No amount* of mucking about with server level configuration is likely to help you [much].

I'm assuming, here, that because you tagged this as "Oracle" that you mean "Oracle Database", the DBMS sold (for money) by Oracle Corporation and *not* "MySQL", another DBMS entirely, acquired by Oracle Corporation in the "garage-sale" that was the collapse of Sun Microsystems.

Unfortunately, Oracle Database doesn't have anything as "simple" as a Slow Query log that lists all the misbehaving SQL.  :-(
You need to use things like the Automated Workload Repository (AWR) to work out what's consuming all the resources.  If you're using SQL Developer, see [this forum posting](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4321693/how-can-run-we-awr-report-outside-of-oem-or-without-loging-into-the-db-server) for how to do that.

If you have Oracle Enterprise Manager (OEM) installed and running, this job is even easier.